# Can't connect to postgresql database from IDE while possible from API

Tags: database, postgresql, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a FE project that gets data from an API. The whole stack (Database + API) is running locally. The problem is that when trying to connect to the database from the IDE (I tried on both IntelliJ and Visual studio code), the connection fails saying that the user doesn't exist. At the same time the API can successfully connect to the same database and returns back the right response.

Any hints ?

Comment: Did you make sure that your ide's use the right jdbc driver?

Comment: If it fails with "user doesn't exist" then apparently your API is using a different Postgres user.